# Relatively basic layout is causing lots of OOM exceptions?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_box"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_details"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag_iv"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/details_no_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Age"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_box"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/submit_layout"
            style="@style/ButtonBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/details_copy"
                style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:text="Copy name and open KIK!" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/seek_divider_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/details_copy_old"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Copy name and open KIK"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxWidth="500dp"
            android:text="dffsdfisdojfijsadifojisdofjisdjfiosdjoifjiadjfiojsadiofjisad"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout above seem to be and always has been a source of a lot of error reports in my Crashlytics panel! Specifically for 'Out of memory exceptions'

Also :

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.broakenmedia.kfriendfinder/com.broakenmedia.kikfriendfinder.DetailsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Please find below the full stacktrace over at the crashlytics URL.

http://crashes.to/s/fc83bf45168

I've tried to optimise the layout wherever possible and all image assets have been correctly made for each device density. Not sure what i can do beyond this!

Comment: I'm not convinced it's the layout itself that's causing the issue. I'd take a look at DetailsActivity.java line 67, also, how big is the image you're using?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing here:

`android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (BitmapFactory.java)`

If you are not managing the size of your assets, you will have Bitmap memory issues.  If the assets you're providing are too large, you need to be down sampling them (or just make the actual asset smaller).  Google has a pretty extensive write-up on Bitmap memory management [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: I cant see how i can optimize anymore than i am? I load ALL bitmaps insamplesize to a ridiculously small size to try and combat this and i also tend to avoid downloading/creating bitmaps altogether by having my entire image set loaded by 'Square's' Picasso, which provides resampling AND caching to disk.

Comment: Looks like the crash was on a Galaxy S2 running Android 2.3.5.  If you're already using Picasso and downsampling all of your Bitmaps, I'm not sure what else there is to do.  Memory issues are even worse on devices.  You could try something like detecting if the OS is 2.x and downsampling even further.

Comment: http://share.joescott.me/2846a It seems as though the vast majority are on Android 4.3! so i dont know if im hitting a bug somewhere, at this point, it does certainly seem there isn't much i can do, i just hate leaving in something like this!